# IText7 Accessibility Table Headers

Tags: itext7

I am working on creating accessible pdf with tables and headers with itext7. The problem that I am running into is that I seem to be unable to set the ID property of the header cell.

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
void Main()
{
    var path = Path.GetTempFileName();
    using var ms = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

    var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(ms)).SetTagged();
    var document = new Document(pdfDocument);
    
    var units = new UnitValue[4];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var uv = i switch {
            0 => new UnitValue(UnitValue.PERCENT, 25),
            1 => new UnitValue(UnitValue.POINT, 72),
            3 => new UnitValue(UnitValue.PERCENT, 35),
            _ => null
        };
        
        units[i] = uv;
    }
    
    var table = new Table(units);
    table.UseAllAvailableWidth();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var c = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph($"header {i + 1}"));

        c.GetAccessibilityProperties().SetRole(StandardRoles.TH);
        c.SetProperty(Property.ID, $"header_{i+1}");
        table.AddHeaderCell(c);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        var c = new Cell()
            .Add(new Paragraph($"cell {i+1}").SetMargin(0));
        
        table.AddCell(c);
    }
        
    document.Add(table);
    document.Close();
}
```

When I look at the table header cell properties using Adobe Acrobat pro, the ID property is left blank. Is there a different way to set this property than `cell.SetProperty(Property.ID, "cell id")`?

[image: header cell properties]